# Flask - Redirect via javascript on successful json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, redirect, flask

I am using an ajax function to verify user login and i am returning json on errors . i wanted to redirect to a particular url on successive login, but the i can only send json data from my function (eliminating the possibility of using url_for or redirect ) . so How do i dynamically get the root url so i can send it via json and then redirect via javascript.
heres my route`

```
def logincheck():
    uname = request.form['username']
    pwd = request.form['password']
    if uname and pwd:
        this = userlogin.query.filter_by(username = uname).first()
        if this:
            if this.password == pwd:
                session['myid'] = this.uid
                return jsonify(success = ?)
            else:
                return jsonify(p_error = 'Incorrect Password')
        else:
            return jsonify(u_error = 'Incorrect Username')
```

Thanks.

Comment: So i ended up using location.reload() to refresh the page, since the user had been logged in. a refresh automatically redirected to the desired page/

Comment: Something like this `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pathname,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.redirect) {
        window.location = data.redirectURL;
      }
    }` in your ajax call and pass the redirectURL through flask. In flask `return jsonify(data=data)` where data contains redirectURL etc

Comment: the problem would still have been getting the root url.. since i am testing this on localhost the url would be different than the actuall production server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get base url in javascript ,

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
```

output : "http://yoururl.com"

```
var host = window.location.host;
```

output : yoururl.com

To redirect url in javascript ,

// redirect to another page

```
`window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"`;
```

// it has similar behavior as an HTTP redirect

```
window.location.replace("http://yoururl.com");
```

// it has similar behavior as clicking on a link

```
window.location.href = "http://yoururl.com";
```

Hope this will help you.